# Pipe User-Input String to Command in Windows Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to automate a simple task.

This task requires that I login into an application. And this application requires I enter a password!

A simple attempt to login on command line would be like:

```
vv -u myuser login
Enter password:
```

And this waits for my input.

How can I pass my password to it?

I tried the following

```
echo "mypassword" | vv -u myuser login

echo "mypassword" | -S vv -u myuser login
```

Neither worked! It's actually returning "Invalid password" but if I type the password manually it works.

Comment: That depends on what `vv` is; I've never heard of this program.

Comment: In case your password is stored in a text file `mypasswordfile.txt` (in a single line, without any leading and/or trailing white-spaces, and without any surrounding quotation marks), use `vv -u myuser login < "mypasswordfile.txt"`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
echo(mypassword| vv -u myuser login
```

no spaces or quotes around the password

Comment: `echo(` is the safe variant of `echo`. A password like `/?:$` fails with `echo /?:$` as it prints the help text of the echo command